# Series of measurable functions and series of Lebesgue integral

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $f_n:(0,1) \to \mathbb R$, $f_n(x)=nx^{n-1}-(n+1)x^n$. Prove that $$\int_{(0,1)} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_n \neq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_{(0,1)} f_n$$

Check that $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_{(0,1)}|f_n|=\infty$$

I am having some problems with calculations, I'll write what I could do:

For each $n$, $$\int_{(0,1)}f_n=(x^n-x^{n+1})\Bigg|^{1}_{x=0}=0,$$so $$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_{(0,1)} f_n=0$$

I am having some difficulty calculating the other two remaining expressions of the problem:

$$\int_{(0,1)}|f_n|=\int_0^{\frac{n}{n+1}}(nx^{n-1}-(n+1)x^n)dx+\int_{\frac{n}{n+1}}^1((n+1)x^n-nx^{n-1})dx$$$$=2(\dfrac{n}{n+1})^n-2(\dfrac{n}{n+1})^{n+1}$$

I don't know how to prove thatthe series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2(\dfrac{n}{n+1})^n-2(\dfrac{n}{n+1})^{n+1}$$is divergent and I don't know how to calculate $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}nx^{n-1}-(n+1)x^n$$

Any help with these two calculations would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

When you have such a series, I wonder if you have in mind all well-known tricks to find their sum.

- Standard tricks are differentiating or integrating known series.  That's how one finds the Taylor series of the arc tangent.
- Another common device is to spot telescoping series, i.e. imagine that the general term of a series $a_n$ is of the form
  $$a_n=b_{n+1}-b_n,$$
  for $n\geq 2,$ and $b_1=a_1.$

  Then its sum is clearly the limit of
  $$a_1+\dots +a_n= b_{n+1}-b_n + b_n - \dots + b_2-b_1 + b_1= b_{n+1}.$$

You should see whether any of this general advice fits your case.